# Help with Geth Setup, sync stalled?

Tags: go-ethereum

since i hit the command `geth --rpc --fast --cache=1024` just about 48 hours ago i've been stuck here...well it did finish something first, but then started this on its own...

[image]

any ideas whats going on with my status? you're answers are appreciated.

Comment: What version of geth are you running?

Comment: Are you saying it stopped pulling chain segments or is still going?

Comment: no im saying that its still pulling, but that since im a noob at this, im not sure what the hell its doing :D

Comment: Nothing wrong, you are using a fast synch. 
the current block is 3972738 and you are still at 3972680 so you are close

Comment: @Crema im not sure how to check on version and it doesnt say. :(

Comment: @BadrBellaj really!?! thank you! thats great news:D

Comment: if you want the version run : geth --version

Comment: @BadrBellaj well geth is still running setup and currently at number 3972769 ...am i supposed to just keep running ?

Comment: you are sunched then but you will receive new blocks. what's your goal? you want to mine?

Comment: @BadrBellaj "sunched" ? yes im trying to mine ethereum.(update im currently on # 3973989 of the blockchain)

Comment: sorry is was a typo synced. you need to wait untail you get the mesage "fast sync complete, auto disabling"

Comment: @BadrBellaj and when i get this message will the processes stop (like it wont keep making new lines) on CMD ? thank you for your help too by the way. its been reassuring.

Comment: its been over 48 hours and feel it might go to 3 days ...is this normal??? if their is even such a thing with so many different systems out their.

Comment: @Crema v1.6.6-stable-10a45cb5 windows 64

Answer (score 1):

Wait until you get the message **fast sync complete, auto disabling** (wait after that some minutes to get ensured) :

```
I0416 17:16:12.631667   30629 blockchain.go:1251] imported 195 block(s) (0 queued 0 ignored) including 0 txs in 1.235990428s. #384 [d707e667 / d3d5d5c1]
I0416 17:16:12.631825   30629 sync.go:180] fast sync complete, auto disabling
I0416 17:16:48.831757   30629 blockchain.go:1251] imported 4 block(s) (0 queued 0 ignored) including 0 txs in 12.933585ms. #388 [bbb506ab / 0ace7268]
```

Then close using CTRL-D (not CTRL-C)

run `geth console`
and then `miner.start()`

NB : I am not sure if fast sync could be used for mining while i am using a full blockchain sync.

Comment: awesome! ok now that i know what too look for, but in your opinion  ive been syncing for 3 days on a sabertooth motherboard with amd fx8 series and asus strix gtx 970 is this normal if their is a thing?

Comment: Synchronization isn't related to the hardware but to the network throughput you are downloading data online wich could take long time. But as i've noticed you are alreadg synced just wait for thw operation to finish

Comment: So just to clarify...3 days and going is normal for this process/operation, after the sync is already complete? i don't have a problem with waiting, i just want to make sure i'm not doing something wrong and that i'm not waiting for no reason?